# Debt sustainability vs dynamics

Tags: government-debt, government-spending

Im having trouble understand the difference, I have both the equations but still fail the meaning of each. Cant find any source that explains this. Any help or guidance to where I could find it would be much appreciated

Comment: Could you please specify which equations you are talking about? Debt dynamics and sustainability can be modeled in several different ways

Comment: Debt dynamics can be expressed as follows (in stock and flow terms):

Comment: NDt = (1 + it-1)NDt-1 – PBt-1 (debt stock)
• Ft = (it-1)(NDt-1) + At – PBt-1 (debt flow) – Where it denotes debt financing interest rates; At denotes amortisation of legacy debt; and PBt denotes fiscal primary balance (i.e. T – G)

Comment: Please [edit](https://economics.stackexchange.com/posts/50961/edit) this into the body of your question so that readers don't have to read all the comments to understand it.

Comment: Also it seems you still wrote nothing about deb sustainability.